# Who calls intercept method of interceptor in Struts 2

Tags: java, struts2, struts2-interceptors

I was working with Struts2 interceptors, the container creates the Action proxy for the relevant action class after consulting the configuration manager(`struts.xml`). Now its time to execute the interceptor chain, i have a simple question - who exactly calls the intercept method in the `Myinterceptor` class.

```
public class MyInterceptor  implements Interceptor{

    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void init() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public String intercept(ActionInvocation ai) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        long t1=System.currentTimeMillis();

        ValueStack s= ai.getStack();
        String val=s.findString("name");
        s.set("name", val.toUpperCase()+"_changed");

        return ai.invoke();

    }

}
```

According to my understanding , it is called by the actionproxy of the corresponding action class, on the same lines it is done in spring AOP, where a proxyfactorybean does a similar thing to call the advices for a class(pointcut).

But i don't have any documentation to support this.
Please let me know am i right or not.

Comment: Hey! if you found the answer correct then please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting it as a parameter to a method `intercept`. You don't have to go broadly away from the interceptor instance because the caller passes itself to every interceptor instance when intercepting.

The place where this method is called is [`DefaultActionInvocation`](http://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/DefaultActionInvocation.html)

> ```
> public class DefaultActionInvocation extends Object implements ActionInvocation
> ```
>
> The Default ActionInvocation implementation

Comment: yeah, but i want to know from where exactly is the statement like 'myInteceptor.intercept(ai)' is getting called.

Answer (score 0):

ActionInvocation class

1. Framework first call invoke() method of ActionInvocation to start the execution of Action.
2. ActionInvocaton starts the invocation process by executing first interceptor in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Your intercept must override method `intercept()` of interface `Interceptor`. Just add `@Override` annotation to your method.

```
@Override
public String intercept(ActionInvocation ai) throws Exception {
   //your code
}
```

Comment: It doesn't answer OP question. And `@Override` annotation is just a marker.

Comment: After an interceptor is created method init is called in Interceptor interface. Then init calls intercept. But to call your method interceptor you must override. For more you can read in these articles:
https://struts.apache.org/maven/xwork-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/interceptor/AbstractInterceptor.html and 
https://struts.apache.org/maven/xwork-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/interceptor/Interceptor.html#intercept(com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionInvocation)

Comment: The `init` method doesn't call `intercept` method. Method overriding isn't achieved with `@Override` annotation (it is just marker).